# Refresh one component from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, nodes, reload

I have Tow components, the first one `clintVote.vue` the second one is `Status.vue`, the first one is for the client to vote, and the second one is in the dashboard for the admin to see the Status of voting.
the problem is how to refresh the `Status.vue` component in real-time to see the status of the voting
**Note:** the two components in different route

Comment: it depends on which chart library you are using, one library you only need to check the input data, others you can use chart instance's refresh method

Comment: I edit the question, the problem is not in the chart lib, is about between two components in real-time